# Python Scrapy can't startproject tutorial OSX 10.11.3

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

I installed python3 via brew, I got virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper installed and setup a virtual enviroment. I activated a virtual enviroment and installed scrapy using `pip3.5 install scrapy` (later on i also used `pip`and `pip3`- I think its weired that I got 3 diffrent versions but well it is what it is)

my ~/.bash_profile has:

`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.5
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON`

`PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/bin/python3.5:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH`

`export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

however, when I run `scrapy startproject tutorial` I get a bunch of errors, btw. there is no difference if I run the command while my virtual env is activated or not. I even tried to manually set the Path for scrapy within the command - still no luck.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/b101/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(execute())
File "/Users/b101/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 122, in execute
cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
File "/Users/b101/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
File "/Users/b101/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
File "/Users/b101/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 21, in _iter_command_classes
for obj in vars(module).itervalues():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'
```

does somebody know how I can fix this or make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Please try `pip install scrapy==1.1.0rc3` (scrapy 1.0.5 does not support Python3)

Comment: YOU SIR! are a frickin life saver :D Thanks mate, worked like a charm! post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: oh btw. I also added `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` to my PYTHONPATH inside my .bash_profile - so I don't know if this was necessary